# Possible regression losses for object detection

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, object-detection, bounding-box, loss-function

Many object detection algorithms predict bounding boxes as (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) meaning the top-left and the bottom-right corner of a bounding box. Besides, in order to avoid exploding gradients the majority of the papers suggest smooth L1 loss or simply L1 loss.

My question is, are there any successful attempts of other approaches?

For instance

- Predict the top-left point (x,y), the width and the height of the box.
- Predict the center point (x,y), the width and the height of the box.
- Predict the center point (x,y), the size and the aspect ratio of the box.
- Predict the center point (x,y), the size and tan<sup>-1</sup>(aspect ratio)

Moreover, some of these options might include different importance / weights for some attributes. E.g. it might be more important to find a good center point and size than a well-fitted aspect ratio. Also, it might be wise to use L1 loss for the center point but L2 for size or aspect ratio. Is there any research on this topic you know about?

Thanks.